# MongoDB add new field using value of another field

Tags: mongodb

How can i update  all documents in my collection from this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "16-00-003", 
    "pickUpPlace" : {
        "place_id" : "someId", 
        "latitude" : 21.912363052368164, 
        "longitude" : 24.804792404174805
    }
}
```

into this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "16-00-003", 
    "place_id" : "someId", 
    "location" : [21.912363052368164, 24.804792404174805]        
}
```

Comment: `"location" : {21.912363052368164, 24.804792404174805}` is not valid JSON. May be you want `"location" : [21.912363052368164, 24.804792404174805]`?

Comment: yes, sorry) need double array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) operations process data records and return computed results.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 1,
      "place_id": "$pickUpPlace.place_id",
      "location": [
        "$pickUpPlace.latitude",
        "$pickUpPlace.longitude"
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

### How to update

1. *Slow*. If you have small amount of data, you may iterate over results and save them into the same collection:

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([...]).forEach(function(doc){
    db.collection.save(doc);
})
```

---

2. *Fast*. [`$out` or `$merge`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html#comparison-with-merge) operators take the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline and writes them to a specified collection (you cannot insert inside source collection).

**The trick part:** write result inside new collection and drop old one.

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 1,
      "place_id": "$pickUpPlace.place_id",
      "location": [
        "$pickUpPlace.latitude",
        "$pickUpPlace.longitude"
      ]
    }
  },
  { $out : "collection2" }
])
```